# What does "On an episode by episode basis" mean?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I was reading this article https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2851344/# and in the conclusions section I bumped into such phrase.

> Evaluators of the safety of APAP and ibuprofen must bear in mind the
> millions of children who receive these drugs every day worldwide and
> the fact that use of APAP has been far more extensive than ibuprofen.
> At this point, it appears unlikely that a serious risk such as the
> association between ASA and Reye’s syndrome will surface for APAP.
> However, the same cannot yet be said with the same degree of certainty
> for ibuprofen, and until adverse event data collected over a period of
> years prove conclusively that rare serious events are not associated
> with ibuprofen, APAP must remain the drug of choice. Ibuprofen should
> be reserved for second-line therapy, and then used **on an episode by
> episode basis**.

Comment: Did you check the dictionary for "episode"? Can you explain what you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: The punctuation is wrong here: on an episode-by-episode basis.

Comment: It's not wrong to omit the hyphens, but the hyphenated form is more common when used to modify a noun. Here are unhyphenated examples from an [academic book](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Conscience_of_James_Joyce/GSrWCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22episode+by+episode+analysis%22&pg=PA107&printsec=frontcover), [British newspaper](https://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk/news/tv/corrie-spoilers-episode-episode-timeline-14694808), [TV website](https://www.screenspy.com/homecoming-recap-season-1-episode-1-mandatory/).

Comment: I just don't understand it, I looked up the meaning for episode but I can't figure out the exact meaning in Spanish

Comment: Are they saying that I should just give ibuprofen to accurately evaluated and individual cases, that I shouldn't give it to everybody as if it were a cuisine recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a more apt phrase for a medical context would be

> ...used on a case-by-case basis

`Episode by episode` simply means to consider each instance in which the medical provider might be deciding whether or not to prescribe Ibuprofen, which would likely mean that the decision to prescribe Ibuprofen depends on each patient's case. `Case-by-case` is just a more commonly used version of the same thing.

The only other meaning of episode by episode is, if you're looking at a single patient who has frequent episodes or bouts of the same illness, then decide each time with that same patient whether or not to use Ibuprofen. I think they mean the broader, more general interpretation though--across patients, not within patients.

Comment: No, I think they mean what they wrote, *episode-by-episode*. They're saying to use APAP on a first-line basis, and to use ibuprofen in second-line by episode, that is, when APAP alone is not sufficient for a particular episode of fever/pain.

Comment: That would make more sense.